# Per regex to parse and replace nested match

Tags: regex, perl

I have text like below with nested [QUOTE][/QUOTE] tags. I want to parse entire nested string usign Perl regex.

```
[QUOTE username=test1]This is test one. [QUOTE username=test2]This is test2. [/QUOTE] This is test3 [/QUOTE]
```

I am using below Perl regex and its parsing first [QUOTE] with its end  [/QUOTE] but its not parsing nested tags.

```
$text =~ s#\[QUOTE\s?(?:username)?(?:=(.*?))?\]([^>]*)?\[\/QUOTE\]#<div class="quoted"><div class="quote-from">$1</div>$2</div>#isg;
```

It is returning below result with just first [QUOTE] parse and leaving middle [QUOTE][/QUOTE] as it is. But I need to parse all nested tags.

```
<div class="quoted"><div class="quote-from">test1</div>This is test one. [QUOTE username=test2]This is test2. [/QUOTE] This is test3 </div>
```

Please help with this.

Comment: Why don't you just replace opening and closing tags separately? Should be way easier.

Comment: Also https://metacpan.org/pod/Parse::BBCode.

Comment: If replace opening or closing tags separately then its also replacing those tags that's have no close or start tags. due to this, wants replace by match start and end tags.

Comment: Then you need to implement a proper grammar. Your language is more complex than what a single line regex can achieve.

Comment: FYI, in the PCRE regex engine you could use a recursive regex for this. F.e. `\[QUOTE.*?\]((?R)|[^\[]*(?:\[[^\[]*)*)\[\/QUOTE\]`.  Not sure how that translates to your perl version though.  But using an actually parser for BBCode might be more dependable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it with a couple of changes:

1. Start replacement from the *last matching* `[QUOTE]`
2. *Repeat* the regex until no more replacements can be made (since the `g` flag doesn't backtrack)

Something like this:

`1 while $text =~ s#^(.*)\[QUOTE\s*(?:username\s*=\s*([^ \]]+))?\](.*?)\[\/QUOTE\](.*?)#$1<div class="quoted"><div class="quote-from">$2</div>$3</div>$4#s;`

The result will be:

`<div class="quoted"><div class="quote-from">test1</div>This is test one. <div class="quoted"><div class="quote-from">test2</div>This is test2. </div>This is test3 </div>`

Comment: Thanks for answer! Can we handle this without while loop with single line regex?

Comment: Not if you want to ensure strict matching between each opening and closing `QUOTE` tag. But you can omit the `g` flag altogether.